# How to augment an enumeration in YANG

Tags: schema, ietf-netmod-yang

Is there a way to augment an enumeration in another module in YANG ? There is no way, in my case, to put all the values in the first module where the enumeration was defined.

Knowing that the enumeration is inside a grouping as follows:

```
grouping mygrouping {
    ...
    container mycontainer {
        ...
        list mylist {
            leaf type {
                type enumeration {
                    enum type1
                    enum type2
                    ...
                    enum typen
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The grouping is used in the new module, but I couldn't augment the leaf type to add new types in the enumeration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In YANG, enumerations are for well-known static set of options.
For extensible options, you can use identityrefs.
This allows identities to be used in multiple files, and to define a leaf with a identityref type, which can then take any of the values of the defined identities.

Think of it as a decentralized enumeration. It's not really 'augmenting' but it does allow to introduce new options to a value without changing the original module.
Of course, this does assume that you can actually change the original leaf with the enumeration.

Definition of identities in YANG RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6020#section-7.16
Some reference on enumeration versus identities: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8407#section-4.11.1

---

Update: one option that is 'sort of' augmenting enums is to define the original enum in a typedef, and then extend it via a union:

```
typedef myenum {
    enum val1 { value 1; }
    enum val2 { value 2; }
    enum val3 { value 3; }
}

...

leaf myleaf {
    type union {
        type myenum;
        type enumeration {
            enum val4 { value 4; }
            enum val5 { value 5; }
        }
    }
}
```

So in this case, the **myleaf** can have values val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, which means the original enum was indeed 'augmented'.

Of course this means it is not really an enum, but a union between two enums, which are arranged so that their values don't intersect (something that unions do allow). This may or may not be a simplification, on both client and server side - depending on the implementation.